# using pytesseract to generate a PDF from image

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I am using the following code to generate a PDF from image.

```
PDF=pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr(test_image,lang='dan',config='',nice=0,extension='pdf')
```

and the type of PDF variable is being shown as BYTES.

HOw Do i publish or get the PDF generated?

Answer (score 6):

I have found the answer. Just to close the thread, posting the same.

```
 f = open("demofile.pdf", "w+b")
 f.write(bytearray(pdf))
 f.close()
```

demofile.pdf happens to be resultant pdf which gets published in the workspace.

Answer (score 5):

From [Pytesseract-PYPI](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/):

> ## Get a searchable PDF

```
pdf = pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr('test.png', extension='pdf')
with open('test.pdf', 'w+b') as f:
    f.write(pdf) # pdf type is bytes by default
```